# How Can I Run Commands In A SFTP Session Via A Bash Script?

Tags: bash, sftp

I am trying to run the `cd` command in a bash script to a SFTP session. My code currently looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
sftp $1@$2
```

and then I want to use `cd` within the SFTP session and other commands too but cd is fine for now. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the batch mode. Quoting the man page:

```
     -b batchfile
             Batch mode reads a series of commands from an input
             batchfile instead of stdin. [...] A batchfile of ‘-’ may be used to indicate standard input.
```

You can use batch mode to run commands in sequence, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo << EOF > sftp-commands-to-run.txt
ls
put myfile.txt
... more commands ...
EOF
sftp -b sftp-commands-to-run.txt $1@$2
```

You can also pass the commands to run via `stdin`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ls myfile.txt | sftp -b - $1@$2
```

Comment: So I do sftp -b and then what? If I do "ls" afterwords on the same line it returns a usage error

Comment: Just updated the answer to clarify.